# Proof continuity of following function: $g(z)=\int_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)-f(w)}{z-w}dw$

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, holomorphic-functions

Suppose $f(z)$ is a analytic in G and $\gamma$ is a curve in G. Show that

$g(z)=\int_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)-f(w)}{z-w}dw$ is continuous in G

I attempted to bound the integral but can’t seem to remove a $|z-z_0|$ term.

Comment: There is certainly something wrong with your notation: it's either $g(w)$ or you are integrating with respect to $w$.

Comment: Right sorry will edit

Comment: You mean continuous on $G-\gamma$? You should be able to show, more generally, that $g(z) = \int_a^b \phi(z,t)\,dt$ is continuous on $G$ for any continuous function $\phi$.

Comment: Yes how would you show that. I be been stuck for the past few hours

Comment: @TedShifrin could you provide a hint and is my solution valid?

Comment: Your solution would take a good deal more work to write out with all the details right. It's highly unlikely that, fixing $z$, the series will converge for all $w\in\gamma$. The thing I suggested you prove — although more general — is really easier to prove. Use compactness of $[a,b]$ to get uniform continuity appropriately.

Comment: @TedShifrin is $\phi$ supposed to be continuous on GxG or are you viewing it as continuous on G i.e just as a function of t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use my answer in the following along with the fact that continuous functions on a compact set are uniformly continuous: [Prove continuity of the following Function (Question in Conway)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2906033/prove-continuity-of-the-following-function-question-in-conway/2906041#2906041)

Comment: In the linked post you proved continuity of $\phi $ in $GxG$. So is the compact set you'r referring to $\gamma$ or $\gamma x \gamma$?

Comment: @JhonDoe Take $z_n \to z$. Consider the compact set $\{z,z_1,z_2,...\} \times \gamma$ and use uniform continuity on this set. If you prefer you can use $\overset {-} B(z,r)$ (with small enough $r$) in place of $\{z,z_1,z_2,...\}$.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to use only elementary methods, so here is an approach: We will show that $g$ is continuous on $G\setminus\gamma$ (otherwise the integral doesn't make sense). Let $z_0\in G\setminus\gamma$ and let $\delta>0$ be such that the circle centered at $z_0$ and with radius $\delta$ doesn't intersect $\gamma$ (for example, $\delta=\frac12dist(z_0,\gamma)$). It follows that $|z_0-w|>\delta$, whenever $w\in\gamma$. Now let $|z-z_0|<\delta/2$. Then for any such $z$ and for any $w\in\gamma$, we have that $|z-w|>\delta/2$. After some basic algebra we see that
$$g(z)-g(z_0)=(z-z_0)\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(w)}{(z_0-w)(z-w)}dw+(f(z)-f(z_0))\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{(z-w)}dw-f(z_0)(z-z_0)\int_{\gamma}\frac1{(z_0-w)(z-w)}dw.$$

The first integral can be bounded by $\frac2{\delta^2}ML$, where $M$ is an upper bound for $|f|$ and $L$ is the length of $\gamma$. The second and third integral are similarly bounded by $\frac2{\delta}L$ and $\frac2{\delta^2}L$ respectively. For the second term you should also use the fact that $f$ is continuous, since it is analytic, in order to make the difference $f(z)-f(z_0)$ small. You should be able the figure the $\epsilon-\delta$ details on your own.